# How to make my bicycle run faster?

Tags: bicycle

Usually(always) I am in a hurry. So I want my bicycle to run faster. What can I do rather than oiling to make it run really fast in a single paddle.

Comment: I don't really see how this require a life hack, especially if oiling it didn't help. I think the only thing you can really do is peddle faster.

Comment: There is a Bicycles StackExchange site that this would be better for.

Comment: only go down the hills

Comment: Upgrade the engine - that's your legs.  Squats, weights, and endurance exercises for your legs and core muscles.  Aerobic fitness for your lungs.  If you smoke, stop.

Answer (score 2):

Pump up your tires! In my experience, even when in a hurry, the extra time spent on getting the tires up to maximum pressure usually pays off.

Comment: hmm, then i guess losing weight, carrying less weight of items with you, and also getting stronger leg muscles would really help out too

Comment: To a point, yes more air in the tyres/tires helps.  But too much and you end up with an uncomfortable buzzy or bumpy ride.  As the tyre cross section size grows, the lower the air pressure required, which is why MTBs have big 2" tyres, and now 4" fatbikes exist.